# Copying data to Azure using BCP shows no errors but no data is transferred

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bcp

I'm attempting to use `bcp.exe` to insert rows into an Azure database.

The command line I am using is:

```
bcp <database>.dbo.<table> IN <datafile> -n -S <server> -U <username> -P <password> -k -e <errorfile>
```

When executed against a local database, all is fine, the data is inserted.

When executed against the Azure database, `bcp` says all rows were sent to SQL Server, the error file is empty, the Azure resource usage shows a spike, but no data has made it into the database.

- I have tried a data file with a single row.
- I have tried `-c` and `-w`.
- When executing a similar insert using SSMS, the data is inserted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the tcp syntax in your server name (i.e. tcp:servername.database.windows.net) and a user name convention of username@servername?

I followed this article with success: http://thecodegarden.net/bulk-insert-azure-sql/

Otherwise what you have looks good.

Comment: Not using tcp prefix and not the @ convention. I also followed the advice in that link. As I say, stuff seems to be happening at the server. I'm thinking it probably fails due to identity_insert as although switched off using ssms before running bcp, I believe this applies only to the session in which it is set and won't be seen by the bcp session. The fact that no errors are produced is not helpful.